# Values being added to all the indexs of the arrayList instead of last index when '.add()' method for arraylist is being used

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am trying to iterate a list of integers, and generate an object for each value of the list. I want to store that object in another list. I am using the following code.

```
 public String getPersonalDetails() {
  ViewAssociateDetailsVo detailsVo=null;
  try {
  List<ViewAssociateDetailsVo> personalDetailsList=new ArrayList<ViewAssociateDetailsVo>();
  for(int i=0;i< staffIdList.size();i++){
   detailsVo=new ViewAssociateDetailsVo();
    detailsVo=viewDetailsService.getPersonalDetails(staffIdList.get(i));
   System.out.println(detailsVo.getStaffID());
    personalDetailsList.add(detailsVo);
   } 
  detailsVoList.addAll(personalDetailsList);
  }catch (OATSException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return "viewReport";

 }
```

The problem i am facing is when i try to add the values in the output object list, the values of all the elements of the output list is being replaced with the values corresponding to the last element of 'staffIdList'. Kindly help....

Comment: You should review if the function viewDetailsService.getPersonalDetails() returns different objects for different staff, or it applies changes to the same object. If the same object is returned, then you might encounter the problem with getting the values valid for the last in all elements. Additionally, please note that the detailsVo=new ViewAssociateDetailsVo(); will do nothing as you overwrite the new object reference with the object returned from viewDetailsService.

Comment: viewDetailsService.getPersonalDetails() is returning different values all the time . System.out.println(detailsVo.getStaf fID()) is also printing different value for each iteration of for loop

Comment: Try to print the identity hash-code of the detailsVo objects returned from the service. System.out.println(System.identityHashCode(detailsVo)). These will be different, if the getPErsonalDetails() will return different objects for different staffIds.